# SQLite query three tables

Tags: sql, android, sqlite, cursor

I'm working on an Android app that will display some information from a sqlite database in a listview. I need some help sorting out my query.

The database looks like this:

```
[monitors] 1 --- <has> --- * [results] 1 --- <has> --- * [steps]

Table monitors has columns: _id | warning_threshold | alarm_threshold | monitor_name
Table results  has columns: _id | monitor_id        | timestamp       | test_info
Table steps    has columns: _id | result_id         | correct         | response_time
```

I'm trying to make a query that would return:
1) All rows & columns from  the monitors table.
2) The newest test_info for each monitor from the results table.
3) Count the number of correct = true for each result from the steps table.

The returned cursor should look something like this:

```
_id | monitor_name | warning_threshold | alarm_threshold | test_info   | correct_count
1   | 'hugo'       | 1000              | 1500            | 'some info' | 7
2   | 'kurt'       | 800               | 1200            | 'info.....' | 5
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT monitors._id AS _id,
  monitors.monitor_name AS monitor_name,
  monitors.warning_threshold AS warning_threshold,
  monitors.alarm_threshold AS alarm_threshold,
  results.test_info AS test_info
  FROM monitors
  LEFT JOIN results
  ON monitors._id = results.monitor_id
  ORDER BY results.timestamp ASC) AS inner
GROUP BY inner._id;
```

I almost got it working. I am able to get the info from monitors and results, I still need to get the correct_count. Any help with sorting out this query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably something like INNER JOIN (COUNT(*) as correct_count, _id FROM steps WHERE correct = true GROUP BY _id) as counts ON counts._id = monitors._id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach, using a combination of Left Joins, sub queries, and correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT monitors._id AS _id,
 monitors.monitor_name AS monitor_name,
 monitors.warning_threshold AS warning_threshold,
 monitors.alarm_threshold AS alarm_threshold,
 LastResults.test_info AS test_info,
 COUNT(CorrectSteps._id) AS correct_count
FROM monitors
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT * FROM results as r1 where timestamp =
   (SELECT Max(r2.timestamp) FROM results AS r2 WHERE r1.monitor_id=r2.monitor_id)) LastResults
ON monitors._id = LastResults.monitor_id
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT * FROM steps WHERE correct = 'true') CorrectSteps
ON LastResults._id = CorrectSteps.result_id
GROUP BY monitors._id;
```

Comment: I don't know how you keep your `correct` field. SQLite has no boolean type, I'm just supposing a string, but you might have a 1 or 0 setup.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear on if you want the correct steps count on all results, or just the correct steps count on the latest result. I did the 2nd.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this query does exactly what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. I haven't been able to test it out but hopefully it will at least get you started. Note that this query is **not even close** to optimized. Wrote it quickly during my lunch :)

```
SELECT m._id,
       m.monitor_name,
       m.warning_threshold,
       m.alarm_threshold,
       (SELECT r.test_info
          FROM results r
         WHERE r.monitor_id = m._id
         ORDER BY r.timestamp ASC
         LIMIT 1) as 'test_info',
       (SELECT COUNT(_id)
          FROM steps s
         WHERE s.result_id IN (SELECT _id FROM results WHERE monitor_id = m._id)
           AND s.correct = 'true') as 'correct_count'
  FROM monitor m
```

Comment: +1 for the use of correlated subqueries as columns. I didn't know SQLite supported that!